# Perforce p4 "describe" command does not list affected files

Tags: perforce

When "p4 describe changelist#" is issued, sometimes the affected files are listed; sometimes they are not and just show:

Affected files ...

Anyone knows why that is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely explanation: You do not have 'list' rights for the affected files. The docu for [p4 protect](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/protect.html) explains the respective rights.

For example, if you have `list`, but no `read` rights, `p4 describe` will output:

```
Affected files:
   //depot/path/to/file
Difference:
   ...
```

Likewise, if the `list` right is also missing, `p4 describe` will have the output that you saw. Check with your Perforce admin what the rights are for the respective depot path (let him  issue `p4 describe` for the mentioned checklist :))

Comment: would this be true if you issued a 'p4 describe -s //depot/path/to/file'?  I ask because it seems that you would only need list permission to see the files that were in the affected changelist and would only need read permission if describe was actually going to display the diffs.

Comment: First off, 'p4 describe' only takes changelist-numbers, not paths. But stuff like 'p4 files' also require the list right (even though I can't test this right now to be sure). The paths where you lack rights also just don't show up in p4v.

Comment: Yes, you are right about describe.  Was typing my comment too quickly.  I usually use the -s flag with describe and don't get diffs.  That made me wonder about permissions required for the command and if they would be different depending on whether you used -s or not.

Answer (score 4):

If the changelist only contains shelved files, you will see that behavior.  For example:

```
d:\projects>p4 describe -s 925745
Change 925745 by mark.allender@client-mark.allender on 2011/08/11 07:48:04 *pending*

      New SDK

Affected files ...
```

but since I have files that are shelved, I can use the -S option with describe to see the files that are shelved.

```
d:\projects>p4 describe -S -s 925745
Change 925745 by mark.allender@client-mark.allender on 2011/08/11 07:48:04 *pending*

        New SDK

Shelved files ...

... //path/to/fileA#8 edit
... //path/to/fileB#11 edit
... //path/to/fileC#1 edit
... //path/to/fileD#3 edit
```

Also, it will display no files if there are indeed no files in the changelist, which might be the case for pending changelists.  Notice that the first line of the describe output above says *pending*, which means that this changelist hasn't been submitted yet.  Pending changelists can be empty, contain files, contain files and shelved file, or only shelved files.  Depending on that state, the output of 'p4 describe' might not show any files.

Comment: Thanks, but the changelists I was trying to describe are submitted changelists that are not shelved. Any ideas?

Comment: If a changelist is not yet submitted, another possibility is that the changelist exists on another edge server (or proxy) that you're connecting to / running the commands on.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: files or file revisions have been obliterated.

Obliterating can leave submitted changelists that refer to no files.